# .htaccess: rewrite .htm urls internally to .php, but also redirect .php urls to .htm

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a php site. For all of the page links I use foo.htm, and internally rewrite this to foo.php with .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This works great - however, it still allows you to use the foo.php url. I would like to 301 redirect foo.php to foo.htm to prevent any old foo.php search engine results from hanging around and rewrite the foo.htm url internally to foo.php

I can't figure out how to do this without creating a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s(.+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1.htm [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1.htm [NC,R]
```

the option L stops the rewriting engine, preventing a loop.

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't work - it still causes a loop, using the directory path of the server. The browser will stop the loop and say something like "http://example.com/var/html/var/html/var/html/foo.htm" has resulted in too many redirects. This happens for both foo.htm and foo.php

Comment: Tried [NC,S=1] instead of [NC,L] - it behaved the same